# Connect my API with PowerApps but in a Standard way that is not Premium

Tags: .net, api, powerapps

I have created APIS in .net I have managed to connect with PowerApps and use them, after seeing several tutorials, but I get as Premiun with the diamond icon, they can help me how to create or connect in a standard way or maybe in another way that is not Premium form.

[image: Imagen de la evidencia Api Premium]

Comment: does this help ? https://powerapps.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/building-a-custom-api-for-powerapps-using-azure-app-service-web-apps/

Comment: It appears the link you provided, from 2016, called the implementations "Custom API's". I believe this has morphed into the "Custom Connectors" we know today and hence is premium.

Answer (score 0):

The only Data Sources that I know of that are "free" are Sharepoint and Excel (you still need an M365 license that includes Sharepoint). I do not believe you can connect to any custom API's without premium licensing.